# Layouts and Button

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout

```
TableLayout relativeLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        TableRow row =new TableRow(this); 
        Button button ;
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i = 0;i<=13;i++){
                counter++;
                button = new Button(this);
                button.setText(counter);


                row.addView(button);

            }

        relativeLayout.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        relativeLayout.computeScroll();
```

XML File

```
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/ll1"  android:shrinkColumns="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"></TableLayout>
```

But whenever i execute my application it just move my buttons in a single row and after 5 buttons all the buttons move out from the screen. i dont' want to add more rows as i don't want to hard-code anything in my code like placing some code if (counter%5==0) then do this and that.

Is there any other way to calculate the width that if the buttons are equivalent to the width of screen then do this or that or any other way like any property in table Layout which simply wrap content of a row?

Comment: If you gonna have just a single row, use LinearLayout! I do not understand actually what you want to do? What should happen when you add buttons to a layout, how should they appear on the screen - a single line, multiple lines ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way to get the exact width of any component in your app. Look at my answer to my question asked a while ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122631/realign-textviews-if-expands-past-container). As you can see, I instantiate a Paint object, but that's not necessary unless you wish to get the width of the text itself. However you must use the density multiplier:

```
float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

That will convert any function that gets the width of a component (in this case, your button) to the actual pixel width on any given devices. So you would get the button width (via invoking the getWidth() function on your Button object) and then multiply by that scaling factor.

Answer (score 0):

Use FlowLayout instead:

http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

GIT project:

https://gist.github.com/1073863

Answer (score 0):

Using [***Contex***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)'s method [***getResources()***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) you can access all the resources for your application's package. The method returns ***Resources*** and you can see [***here***](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) all properties that are available.